# Is it possible to automatically invert the cursor color or current line color color in gvim

Tags: linux, vim, colors, text-cursor

In my current gvim, the cursor color is fixed. But I need to change the color automatically.

Is it possible to automatically invert the cursor color or current line color in gvim?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is.

```
:hi Cursor gui=reverse guibg=NONE guifg=NONE
:hi CursorLine gui=reverse
```

If you use a specific colorscheme, find the corresponding line and change it as above.

If you don't, *append* one of the lines above (without the `:`) to your `~/.vimrc`.

--- EDIT ---

I wrote this [comprehensive gist](https://gist.github.com/romainl/379904f91fa40533175dfaec4c833f2f) in the meantime.

Comment: This is for gVim. For vim?

Comment: OP asked about GVim so OP got an answer for GVim. See `:help ctermbg` for Vim.